# Docker search finds image, but can't pull

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I need to build a `32-bit` Ubuntu Image, so I do

```
➜  ~  docker search 32bit/ubuntu  
NAME                                       DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
32bit/ubuntu                               Ubuntu for i386 (32bit)                         9                    
32bit/ubuntu-upstart                       ubuntu-upstart for i386 (32bit)                 1                    
pgeraghty/casperjs_slimerjs_ubuntu_32bit                                                   0                    [OK]
pgeraghty/slimerjs_ubuntu_32bit                                                            0                    [OK]
cato1971/ubuntu                            Base 32-bit Ubuntu image from cato1971/ubu...   0                    [OK]
osrf/ubuntu_32bit                          Ubuntu 32bit images                             0                    
cato1971/ubuntu-32bit                      Base Ubuntu 32 bit image                        0                    
souzaonofre/ubuntu-32bits                  Ubuntu 32bits images                            0                    
➜  ~  docker pull 32bit/ubuntu 
Pulling repository 32bit/ubuntu
FATA[0001] Tag latest not found in repository 32bit/ubuntu 
➜  ~
```

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`32bit/ubuntu` is not an image, but a repository containing one or more images, each identified by a tag.  When you don't specify a tag, Docker defaults to the tag `latest`, but `32bit/ubuntu:latest` doesn't exist.  [As we can see on the repository's page on the Docker Hub Registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/32bit/ubuntu/tags/manage/), the only tag available is `14.04`, so you need to pull (and run) `32bit/ubuntu:14.04`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the clear explanation. `docker pull 32bit/ubuntu:14.04` worked for me.